# How to translate the text on a picture with google?

Tags: google-translate

I'm not sure if this is the correct part of SE to ask this question but here it goes.

If I would encounter a picture file with unknown text, I could take another picture of it and get it translated with my phone by using [Google Goggles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Goggles), but how would I be able to translate it on my computer? I tried entering the picture link to Google translate, but it said it wasn't able to open the file.

[image: enter image description here!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't about a programming problem, so your question is probably in the wrong section.

However, what you're looking for is an **OCR** service. Use it to extract the text from the image first, then translate it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem to extract the text from a picture is referred as "Scene Text Recognition" in computer vision. If the image is a picture of a pdf/document, the text can be extracted using OCR with quite good accuracy.

But if the text is present in a picture (like picture of a traffic board), the OCR may not always work. In this case you can use some computer vision APIs provided online, for eg:

You can use the [Google Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr) and paste the image link in the "Try It" section to extract out the text.